# Using CustomConverters specified in other assembly throws an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, com-interop

I have two Class Libraries which contains some Presentation part using windows and user controls. Let's say that it is Presentation1 and Presentation2. I have one more CL which is Common, and both Presentation libraries referenced to it. In Common library I've specified a number of custom converters. I use them in both Presentations but in Presentation1 everything works fine, but in Presentation2 the same converters visible during design time but during runtime I receive an exception:

'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '55' and line position '35'.

If I move any of these converters to the Presentation2 and reference them from itself then they will work.

Any suggestions please what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

My Presentation2 xaml:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.PresentationCL2.Presentation.IssuedView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:MyProject.Common.Presentation.Converters;assembly=MyProject.Common">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Converters:IntToStringConverter x:Key="IntToStringConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    ...
     <ComboBox Margin="0, 10" 
               Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeCollection}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SomeCollectionSelectedValue, Converter={StaticResource IntToStringConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  />
   ...
</UserControl>
```

Presentation1 xaml looks identically, but work fine. Presentation2 throws an excpetion on that line where Converter referenced from StaticResources.

Also it worth to notice that when I moved this IntToStringConverter into my Presentation2 library (and it starts working properly as in Presentation1) incide its code I use a number of classes referenced from the same Common assembly and it also works.

**Update2:**

I've tried to handle this exception using DebugView and result provided below:

[1]  Exception message: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '48' and line position '35'.
[2]  Exception help link:
[3]  Exception Source: PresentationFramework
[4]  Exception StackTrace:    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
[5]    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
[6]    at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
[7]    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
[8]    at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
[9]    at SettingsView.InitializeComponent() in ..\Presentation2\Presentation\presentation\SettingsView.xaml:line 1
[10]    at SettingsView..ctor(TobiiEyeTrackingSettingsViewModel viewModel) in ..\Presentation\SettingsView.xaml.cs:line 14
[11]    at Presentation2.MainClass.ShowSetupDialog(Object varHwndParent) in ..\Presentation2\MainClass.cs:line 171
[12] InnerExceptionMessage: The method or operation is not implemented.
[13] InnerExceptionStackTrace:    at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.ResolveBamlType(BamlType bamlType, Int16 typeId)
[14]    at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006SchemaContext.GetXamlType(Int16 typeId)
[15]    at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.Process_ElementStart()
[16]    at System.Windows.Baml2006.Baml2006Reader.ReadObject(KeyRecord record)
[17]    at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.CreateObject(KeyRecord key)
[18]    at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.RealizeDeferContent(Object key, Object& value, Boolean& canCache)
[19]    at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValueWithoutLock(Object key, Boolean& canCache)
[20]    at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.GetValue(Object key, Boolean& canCache)
[21]    at System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Lookup(Object key, Boolean allowDeferredResourceReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
[22]    at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.FindResourceInEnviroment(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
[23]    at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.TryProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference, Boolean mustReturnDeferredResourceReference)
[24]    at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValueInternal(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, Boolean allowDeferredReference)
[25]    at System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
[26]    at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.CallProvideValue(MarkupExtension me, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)

It worth to add that MainClass mentioned on line 11 is ComVisible class registred in system and implemented special interface (lets say ICOMInterface) where:

```
[Guid("... guid here ...")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MainClass : ICOMInterface
{
    ...

    public void ShowSetupDialog(object varHwndParent)
    {
        SettingsView view = new SettingsView();
        view.ShowDialog();
    }

    ...
}
```

If I won't handle this exception then program which call this ShowSetupDialog via implemented iterface return HRESULT 80131501 which is COR_E_SYSTEM which is a SystemException in .Net

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to drill into the exception and get more information - please try and post whatever you find.

In the absence of that information, I can only assume that your Presentation2 library does not have a reference to your common library.

Comment: Presentation2 has reference to common library. I've provied more information for the question ^_^